# Visual C#: Move multiple files with the same extensions into another directory

Tags: c#, file, move

guys. I've got a problem I can't solve:
I have a 2 folders I choose with folderBrowserDialog and tons of files in source directory I need to move to the target directory. But, I have only to move files with a specific extension like .txt or any other extension I can get from textbox.
So how can I do it?

Comment: Ruff Pseudo; DirectoryInfo(sourceDir + "*.somextension").GetFiles().Foreach( (a) => a.Move(targetDir))

Comment: Can you explain how to or give a link where can I find it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First get all the files with specified extension using [Directory.GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) and then iterate through each files in the list and move them to target directory.

```
//Assume user types .txt into textbox
string fileExtension = "*" + textbox1.Text;

string[] txtFiles = Directory.GetFiles("Source Path", fileExtension);

foreach (var item in txtFiles)
{
   File.Move(item, Path.Combine("Destination Directory", Path.GetFileName(item)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**For copying files...**

```
foreach (string s in files)
{
   File.Copy(s, "C:\newFolder\newFilename.txt");
}
```

**for moving files**

```
foreach (string s in files)
{
   File.Move(s, "C:\newFolder\newFilename.txt");
}
```

**Example for Moving files to Directory:**

```
string filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);

foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.txt"))
{
      Directory.Move(file.FullName, filepath + "\\TextFiles\\" + file.Name);
}
```

will `Move` all the `files` from Desktop to Directory "`TextFiles`".