# C# - How to move muliple files with the same extension name to a different directory?

Tags: c#, directory

How do I move muliple files with the same extension name to a different directory?

Comment: Get files with pattern match (*.extension)

Comment: A search on "csharp move multiple files", first result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424844/visual-c-move-multiple-files-with-the-same-extensions-into-another-directory?s=1|77.8944

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:/YourPath/", "*.txt"); //THIS WILL ONLY MOVE TXT FILES

foreach (string s in files)
{
   File.Move(s, Path.Combine("C:/YourOutputPath/", Path.GetFileName(s)));
}
```

PD: Welcome to SO. In future posts try to show you´ve tried something. Otherwise your question is going to be closed and very downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
var extension = ".txt"
var outputPath = Path.GetDirectoryName("C:/Output");
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:/path");
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, extension);


foreach (var file in files)
{
    if (file.ToUpper().Contains(".TXT"))
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",$"/C copy /b {file} {outputPath}");
}
```

Edit: improvements based on NicoRiff's answer