# Windows service to GCP

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, windows-services

I was looking for resources on how to create a simple background service using C# that checks a specific folder for FLAC files and sends them to a GCP bucket, once the file is uploaded successfully the file is erased or moved to another folder. Where can I find something to read about this kind of thing?

Comment: Use Google Search for **Windows services in C#** and **Google Cloud Storage .NET SDK**.

Answer (score 0):

To move a file to another location using c# you can use the move method. The Move method moves an existing file to a new location with the same or a different file name.The Move method moves an existing file to a new location with the same or a different file name in File Move. The Move method takes two parameters. The Move method deletes the original file. The method that renames files is called [File.Move](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dbeniwal321/how-to-move-a-file-in-C-Sharp/)
Example:

```
{  
    File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);  
}  
catch (IOException iox)  
{  
    Console.WriteLine(iox.Message);  
}
```

If you need more examples about File.Move method please [follow this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-move-method-in-c-sharp-with-examples/)

Adding to that, you can use the Directory.GetFiles method to select the file extension, like in the example below.

This is the original thread where the [example was posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424844/visual-c-move-multiple-files-with-the-same-extensions-into-another-directory)

Example:

```
//Assume user types .txt into textbox 
string fileExtension = "*" + textbox1.Text; 
string[] txtFiles = Directory.GetFiles("Source Path", fileExtension); 
foreach (var item in txtFiles) 
{ 
File.Move(item, Path.Combine("Destination Directory", Path.GetFileName(item))); 
}
```

If you want to know more about Directory.GetFiles method [follow this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_)

And concerning GCP,using Cloud Storage Transfer Service you can move or backup data to a Cloud Storage bucket either from other cloud storage providers or from your on-premises storage. Storage Transfer Service provides options that make data transfers and synchronization easier. For example, you can:

- Schedule one-time transfer operations or recurring transfer
  operations.
- Delete existing objects in the destination bucket if they do not have
  a corresponding object in the source.
- Delete data source objects after transferring them.
- Schedule periodic synchronization from a data source to a data sink
  with advanced filters based on file creation dates, file-names, and
  the times of day you prefer to import data.

If you want to know more about GCP Cloud Storage Transfer Service [follow this link](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/overview)

If you want to know more about how to create storage buckets [follow this link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets?hl=en)